# Parse a line using Pattern.compile

Tags: java, xml, parsing, design-patterns, matcher

I am trying to parse following line, myline in Java and it keeps throwing the null value.

Here is my try to get '000000010'.

```
myline = "<status> <id>000000010</id> <created_at>2012/03/11</created_at> <text>@joerogan Played as Joe Savage Rogan in Undisputed3 Career mode, won Pride GP, got UFC title shot against Shields, lost 3 times, and retired</text> <retweet_count>0</retweet_count> <user> <name>Siggi Eggertsson</name> <location>Berlin, Germany</location> <description></description> <url>http://www.siggieggertsson.com</url> </user></status>"
p = Pattern.compile("(?i)<id.*?>(.+?)</id>", Pattern.DOTALL);
m = regex.matcher(myline);
id =m.group(1);
```

Any advice?

Comment: Extracting data from an XML document with regex is a bad idea. Look into an XML parser.

Answer (score 3):

Highly recommend using an XML parser. There's one built into Java, here's an example solution for your problem. Exception handlers omitted for simplicity.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory
        .newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
String input = "<status> <id>000000010</id> <created_at>2012/03/11</created_at> <text>@joerogan Played as Joe Savage Rogan in Undisputed3 Career mode, won Pride GP, got UFC title shot against Shields, lost 3 times, and retired</text> <retweet_count>0</retweet_count> <user> <name>Siggi Eggertsson</name> <location>Berlin, Germany</location> <description></description> <url>http://www.siggieggertsson.com</url> </user></status>";
Document document = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(
        input)));
String value = document.getElementsByTagName("id").item(0)
        .getTextContent();
System.out.println(value);
```

Comment: The problem is I'm not actually dealing with an XML file, it's a text file with the XML input inside. So I don't think using an XML parser will work will it?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be using a regex to parse XML in the first place.

But aside from that, you're not using the regex correctly. It's not enough to instantiate a `matcher` object, you also need to tell it to do something:

```
if (m.find())
{
    id = m.group(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This website may provide you with some info on Parsing XML using Java - http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=152

Answer (score 0):

this works

```
String myline = "<status> <id>000000010</id> <created_at>2012/03/11</created_at> <text>@joerogan Played as Joe Savage Rogan in Undisputed3 Career mode, won Pride GP, got UFC title shot against Shields, lost 3 times, and retired</text> <retweet_count>0</retweet_count> <user> <name>Siggi Eggertsson</name> <location>Berlin, Germany</location> <description></description> <url>http://www.siggieggertsson.com</url> </user></status>";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*<id>(.+)</id>.*");
Matcher m = p.matcher(myline);
if (m.matches()) {
    String id = m.group(1);
    System.out.println(id);
}
```

[***Edit***:] this also works, and it's better:

```
String myline = "<status> <id>000000010</id> <created_at>2012/03/11</created_at> <text>@joerogan Played as Joe Savage Rogan in Undisputed3 Career mode, won Pride GP, got UFC title shot against Shields, lost 3 times, and retired</text> <retweet_count>0</retweet_count> <user> <name>Siggi Eggertsson</name> <location>Berlin, Germany</location> <description></description> <url>http://www.siggieggertsson.com</url> </user></status>";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<id>(.+)</id>");
Matcher m = p.matcher(myline);
if (m.find()) {
    String id = m.group(1);
    System.out.println(id);
}
```

Comment: Both of these fail if there is more than one `<id>` in the string, if the `<id>` tag has any attributes, or if the contents of the tag contains newlines.

Comment: sure, I completely agree with the "you shouldn't be using a regex to parse XML" part of your comment